# IntelliJ doesn't find classes in current package

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am working through a simple Java annotation example: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/

Being new to Java and IntelliJ, I'm not entirely sure how to set it up, so I did it like this:

[image: IntelliJ]

IntelliJ has a ton of squiggly red lines, so the project must have some error. Do you know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **project name** is `com`, it's not the first folder of a package.

And `mykong` isn't a standard java project source folder, and neither is `core`.

You need to create a new Java / Maven / Gradle project, and use the standard layout of `ProjectName/src/main/java/com/mykong/package`

Comment: This sort of works, now there's another problem (related?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957079/why-does-intellij-says-package-name-does-not-correspond-to-file-path-when-they-d

Answer (score 1):

Have you marked the source root correctly?

It seems like `com` is being interpreted as a module, instead I think you need to move it under a source root.

To resolve:

1. Create a folder in your project (at the top) named `src`
2. Right click `src` and mark it as a source root
3. Move the `com` folder under `src`

Then, it should resolve the packages correctly.

Comment: doesn't it require src/main/java/com.. ?

Comment: @Shenal yes it could also be this, if you are using maven. If you're not using maven, then `src/com/...` is fine.